# What is root cgroup process behavior on Debian?

Tags: linux, docker, debian, cgroups

I am investigating how docker shares resources with the host OS on Debian. Processes run outside of docker will be run in the root cgroup. So it boils down to how resources are shared between the root cgroup and the docker parent cgroup "docker".

For red hat, the behavior is laid out here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/process_behavior.html

When testing with Debian however, I don't see this behavior. When I run multiple processes under the root cgroup I see the following:

1 Process in each cgroup:

```
/rootgroup/ 1 process:    50% 
/rootgroup/docker/ 1 process: 50%
```

2 Processes in the root cgroup:

```
/rootgroup/ 2 processes:    25% + 25%
/rootgroup/docker/ 1 process: 50%
```

I can't find any documentation that lays this behavior out for Debian. Am I seeing the correct behavior? And why does it differ from Red Hat?